# How can I load Field1 and Field2 from TADOQuery to TTreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tadoquery

I want information from `TADOQuery` to be loaded into a `TTreeView`. For example, I want it to be loaded as `Field1->Add` in `Table1` and as `Field2->AddChild` with `buttonClick`. But when I run the code, I am getting an error:

> Access violation at adress 0043616B in module "TRV2.exe"

I'm making a mistake or something is missing. Can you guide me?

```
procedure TForm1.AddButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
var
  t: Integer;
  MyNode, Node : TTreeNode; 
begin 
  MyNode := Node;
  t := Node.AbsoluteIndex;
  TreeView1.Items.Add(MyNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_NAME').AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddChildButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
var
  t: Integer;
  MyNode, Node: TTreeNode; 
begin 
  MyNode := Node;
  t := Node.AbsoluteIndex;
  TreeView1.Items.Add(MyNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_CHILD').AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  t: Integer;
  MyNode, Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  MyNode := Node;
  t := Node.AbsoluteIndex;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: I want to get the whole table and update the `TTreeView` when I add new Add and Child to the database. With these codes (`AddButtonClick` and `AddChildButtonClick`) I can only import the first values into the `TTreeView`. I wonder if a loop is needed?

Comment: `MyNode:=Node;` is problematic: Both are uninitialized local variables and their value is random.  Accessing Node or MyNode is likely to generate an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

`MyNode` and `Node` are both local variables that you are not initializing to anything. Your AV is because you are trying to access an object that doesn't exist.

Try using a class member instead, where you initialize it with one button click, and then use it with the other button click, eg:

```pascal
private
  MyNode: TTreeNode;

...

procedure TForm1.AddButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  MyNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_NAME').AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddChildButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  if MyNode <> nil then
    TreeView1.Items.AddChild(MyNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_CHILD').AsString);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: to iterate through multiple records in the query result, you need to call [`TADOQuery.Next()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Next) in a loop until [`TADOQuery.Eof`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof) is true.

Comment: while not ADOQuery1.Eof do //This line does not run the post-compiler program.

Answer (score 0):

> `The database was taken into treview with the following codes. There is  something missing. Because Field1=Add and Field2=Child. Same Fields repeating.`

```
procedure TForm1.AddButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
CurrentDeptID, RecordDeptID: Integer; RootNode, DeptNode: TTreeNode;
begin
CurrentDeptID := 0;
TreeView1.Items.Clear;
RootNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(DeptNode, 'CODE_NAME');
DeptNode := nil;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from Tablo1 where CODE_NAME= CODE_NAME';
ADOQuery1.Open;
try
ADOQuery1.First;
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
RecordDeptID := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
if ( DeptNode  = nil) or (RecordDeptID <> CurrentDeptID) then
begin
DeptNode := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, 
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_NAME').AsString); //
CurrentDeptID := RecordDeptID;
end;
TreeView1.Items.AddChild(DeptNode, 
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_CHILD').AsString);
ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
finally
ADOQuery1.close;
end;
end;

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNojV.jpg]
```

> Blockquote